# Did not receive site association bonus (+100 rep)

Tags: bug, status-completed, association-bonus, sign-up

I'm a long time user with more than 1500 rep on the main site I visit. I have recently joined the physical fitness beta site and [have not been awarded the site association bonus](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/users/24441/deathismyfriend?tab=reputation).

I believe this is a bug in the beta portion of the site. I have gotten the association bonus on all other sites I have joined.

Comment: You joined today on that site, right? Maybe it is caching but I recall on earlier sites I joined it was always instantaneous. Nothing strange happened at sign-up/joining? Did you had to change your displayname there to match your other profiles?  When you joined were you logged in on any of the *.stackexchange.com sites or only on StackOverflow.com?

Comment: I had very bad service at the time. It said I was logged in later I realized it said I was my normal name but when I checked the profile on the physical fitness site I had a random name. Later that changed to my normal  sign on of deathismyfriend. All other sites have been immediately given.

Comment: ok, you had the same issue that was reported [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/340630/578411). I linked also to this one and pinged Adam.

Comment: I didn't use the google sign on though. I used the sing on with stack exchange. But the rest of it is exactly what had happened to me. I didn't notice that question when I was looking.

Comment: The issue is not related to Google, if i understand Adam's comment correctly. It seems a timing issue which matches your remark about the bad service (I assume that is the network service). That you are using SE as login provider is good, that can prove that the bug is not related to the type of provider.

Comment: @rene That would make sense as too why this happened.

Comment: This happened to me the other day, I fixed it by deleting the profile which stuffed up and re-creating it.

Comment: It's already linked to my account. It says it will delete my main account not he one that was created. Thanks though.

Comment: Actually,  I had the same problem on Open Data Beta.  I joined 3 weeks ago and never got the association bonus.

Answer (score 5):

Not 100% sure *what* the bug is, but I fixed your immediate issue. You should see the association bonus on your Fitness profile now.

With all the reports recently, I'm reasonably convinced that something is broken in how we propagate existing profiles to new sites in the network. It is, unfortunately, difficult to reproduce. I'll have to give it another try. In the meantime, please let me know if you're still experiencing any other issues.